# Understanding Laravel Eloquent and traditional table mapping

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to understand laravels eloquent mapping functionality.
If I've 3 tables:

```
Article
Asset
ArticleAssetMap
```

Article: A simple table, ID, title, body, dates etc.

Asset: asset path, dates etc

ArticleAssetMap: two colums. article_id, asset_id

I need to understand how to describe to my model(s) that when I request all or some articles, to check the map table and IF there's a map found, get the asset too...

I've got models for all the tables above, and reeeeally think it has to do with eloquents onetomany/belongsto etc etc... but can't find a decent tutorial to break that down for me... am I being dumb.. is there a nice way to 'get it..?

Comment: By default, laravel eloquent looks for the "correct column" name. For example asset table will have a asset_id as its primary key. In the documentation, specifying PK and FK can be done by adding additional params on the model.

Comment: ah, my asset table only had 'id' as the priamry key... should that be renamed to asset_id and the same for article etc?

Comment: yeah or try specifying the field names. Also use laravel's artisan to create models and migrations. Here's the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your third table as `article_asset` and then do the following.

in your `Article` class

```
// if one article has many assets
public function assets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
}

// if one article has only one assets
public function asset()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Asset::class);
}
```

in your `Asset` class

if an asset belongs to one article

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
}
```

if an assets belongs to many article

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

You're good to go now.

Comment: Actually, this might be the case of Many to many. ie An asset may belong to many articles, and an article may contain many assets.

Comment: Added an article  may contain many assets scenario. Adding others.

Comment: Hm.. no.. based on the table schema, clearly `ArticleAssetMap` is a pivot table. Most like we'll want only `->belongsToMany()` here.

Comment: This is GREAT.. so I don't need an Model for my renamed table artice_asset anymore?

Comment: Yes, if you're doing it by Laravel's convention, just by adding `->belongsToMany(Article::class)` on your Asset class it'll use your `article_asset` table as pivot and vice versa; skipping the need for your pivot table model.

Comment: @JofryHS Thanks for your assist

Beertastic: Hope you got your answer. Mark this answer as accepted if you think it was helpful.

Comment: One last Q... So I fetch article object.. and then can access any functions in my asset model via: $article->assetFunction()  that's not working for me...

Comment: Yes you can. Try $article->assetFunction->field_name @Beertastic

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam - Quick final Q.. if I don't need an ArticleAsset model.. what's the laravel way to add to that table in my code?

Comment: You don't need ArticleAsset model. Since you're following the convention of naming third table(pivot table), and you are defining relationships on Article and Asset model class, laravel will take care of the rest. Once you call `$aritcle->assets()` or `$asset->articles()` laravel know what are you are looking for and it will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you may also override the foreign and local keys by passing additional arguments to the hasMany method:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many